# Multiple string variables in a function ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm really new to ios and i'm trying to write a function that recieves 4 string,
Heres what I try:
this is in my h file:

```
-(BOOL)validate:(NSString*)fullname:(NSString*)email: NSString username:(NSString*)password
```

this is in my m file:

```
-(BOOL)validate:(NSString*)fullname:(NSString*)email: NSString username:(NSString*)password
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9A-z._%+- ]+@[A-Za-z0-0.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",emailRegex];
    return YES;
}
```

the errors is get are that iam using an undeclared identifier 
on the emailRegex
and on the emaitTest

Basicly all i'm trying to do is declare a method that recieves 4 strings:
fullname
email
username
password

and implement it.

any help would be good.

good day.

Comment: Is this in your .h file or .m file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be as :

```
-(BOOL)validateFullName:(NSString*)fullName email:(NSString*)email userName:(NSString*)username withPassword:(NSString*)password;
```

For Better readability :

```
-(BOOL)validateFullName:(NSString*)fullName
                  email:(NSString*)email
               userName:(NSString*)username
               password:(NSString*)password;
```

**Edit: Naming convention was not best, so renamed.*

Comment: @BobYaris: That is completely different question. You should remove it from there and post a new fresh question.